# Restfull api design pattern when refer to summary and details of a domain model

Tags: rest, domain-driven-design

For a simple application, there are 2 restfull apis managing users' information.

For example, api A is defined as  **/users** which return a list  of users. api B is defined as **/user/{id}** which return a user identified by his id.

However, the front page using the api A is a summary page displaying a table of a users which only need a few properties of a user, like name, age, gender, etc.. When refer a details of a user's information, there are much more properties are needed, like social security number, bank accounts, and there properties are not stored in the database but in some other system.

So, should I using different apis for there these two scenario, like **/userSummaries** and **/userDetailes/{id}** and just using apis I mentioned above？

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: How is that related to DDD? What would be the difference between `/users` and `/user/{id}` vs `/userSummaries`and `/userDetailes/{id}`? Is your question just about how to name your URIs?

Answer (score 1):

You should have an api for every `bounded context`.

That being said, you should somehow map the write and the read models to the api endpoints. `Aggregates commands` should be mapped to put/post/patch/delete endpoints. `Read-models` queries should match the get api endpoints.

UPDATE:

> So, should I using different apis for there these two scenario, like
>   /userSummaries and /userDetailes/{id} and just using apis I mentioned
>   above？

Yes. You should have an API end point to each Read-model.

See https://vimeo.com/41763224 and https://yow.eventer.com/events/1004/talks/1047

Comment: The two api endpoints I talked about are all about read models, I can not get the point.

Comment: I tried to include in the response the API endpoints to the write model too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would separate the two APIs. In the API layer, you have different models for the response(eg. UserSummaryModel, UserProfileModel). These models will act as view models or DTOs(data transfer objects). They are anemic classes that contains only getters and setters. The rich domain which is in a separate project will contain the User(and other domain models) business logic, constraints, validations, etc.

So in the API layer, you have to map the view models to the domain model. You can manually do the mapping or use Automapper.

Answer (score 0):

@Constantin GALBENU is right what you should have an API for each context but this also depends on your application because there could be cases where you need an API to fetch data from two contexts.

I just want to add that you should not confuse the Domain of your application with the Domain of your API(s). I.E. you can have a generic API that is able to standardly hook to any of your BoundedContexts and expose their functionality either via concrete configuration or some automatized method. 
This not however mean that your API code is part of you App's Domain since the API is only concerned with answering requests/logging/etc. - all things specific to an API.